# Android multi lined text with virtual keyboard suggestion off

Tags: android

I need to disable the soft keyboard suggestion.

I have found this:
`inputtype="textNoSuggestion"`
But when I set this, I'm not able to type the multi lined text?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use,

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

OR

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Whichever suits your need

Have you tried this

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Comment: i don't want to hide the softkeyboard insted i need to disable the word predection ,and need to type multi lined text in edittext

Comment: i have check android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" this
 also,with this ,suggestion is turned off but am not able to write the multi line text